# SQLite query on Android using parameters with spaces

Tags: android, sql

I'm a newbie to SQLite and Android so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Does anyone know a way to pass down a parameter that has spaces in to a non-trivial SQLite database query, something of the form "AAA BBB"

I've tried all the obvious things like placing single quotes around the spot where the parameter will be substituted into the select string.

Actually tried hard-coding ' "AAA BBB" ' into the select string and it still doesn't work. 
Well, it does work at the simple, raw query level, just not as part of a more complex query.

What I mean by that is there doesn't seem to be a way to do the query I want to do as a plain SELECT raw query. I've tried feeding a sub-query into the raw query and that does everything I want it to do except when the parameter has spaces. The same sub-query used as a raw query does handle the parameter with spaces correctly (when the single quotes are added).

The query uses multiple tables so db.Query is not an option.

So now I'm using BuildQueryString and feeding that into rawQuery. Same story. Even when I hard-code the ' "AAA BBB" ' string directly into the input to BuildQueryString. Is there some other way I should be using the result of BuildQueryString.

Anyone know a way to do this???

Comment: Does the string actually have the double quotes around it? If not then  just use `'AAA BBB'`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried various permutations of single/double quotes. They do work in a raw query but not when the parameter is fed into a subquery of the full raw query, or when I put it inside a where clause for query builder. I haven't found a way to build the query I need as a simple raw query

Comment: To be honest, I find the so-called 'convenience' methods of Android SQLite classes and things like query builders to be more inconvenient than anything else. Perhaps I've just been using SQL for so long but I'm more inclined to use `rawQuery` or `execSQL`. You say you have it working with `rawQuery` but you haven't shown us any code for how it works or any code which is failing. Unless you post code, you're not helping anybody here to help you.

Comment: Sorry it's a complex query and I didn't want to post the whole thing. I've found a way to do the query as a raw query, having realized that the order dependence of the conditions in the WHERE clause makes a difference. But now I find that the problem is that one of the words in my problem string is in fact Where. If I give it a different string such as "AAA BBB" it works. If I give it my "WHERE AAA" string I get an error near AAA. Any ideas on how to handle such keywords in positional parameters?

Comment: OK I have it. I realized I the problem string is also being used as part of a bigger string (input to the ORDER BY) clause which I was building up with a String.format. There I DID need to remove the spaces and that's where the error message was coming from all along. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of what you want to do:

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT bar FROM Foo WHERE bar = 'AAA BBB'", null);
```

If SQL injections are a threat and you have "AAA BBB" in `String myName`:

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT bar FROM Foo WHERE bar = ?", new String[] { myName });
```

But I'm not certain what "at a more complex level means"... Perhaps this:

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT bar FROM Foo WHERE bar LIKE ? ORDER BY bar = ?, bar LIKE ?, bar LIKE ?", new String[] { myName, myName, myName + "%", "%" + myName + "%" });
```

Comment: I mess up the comment yesterday. But here is an update. I've found a way to do the query as a raw query, having realized that the order dependence of the conditions in the WHERE clause makes a difference. But now I find that the problem is that one of the words in my problem string is in fact Where. If I give it a different string such as "AAA BBB" it works. If I give it my "WHERE AAA" string I get an error near AAA. Any ideas on how to handle such keywords in positional parameters?

Comment: OK I have it. I realized I the problem string is also being used as part of a bigger string (input to the ORDER BY) clause which I was building up with a String.format. There I DID need to remove the spaces and that's where the error message was coming from all along. Thanks for your help